# Angular8: Loading Different google font per route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8, google-font-api

I am using Angular8 for my frontend project and I am into a situation where I need to use different google font per angular route.

One possible solution is that I import all the google fonts that are needed in the project by importing them in the head section and the just change `font-family` in the component CSS file.
But the drawback here is I need to download all the google font unnecessarily at my 1st app load.

Can anyone suggest a way to load a single google font per route?

Comment: how does that matter here?

Comment: you can have `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tomorrow&display=swap');` at top component `css` or `scss`. which will get loaded on loading that component only. doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@import` in each css or route from which you want to change the google font.

**Component 1 css**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Odibee+Sans&display=swap');

p {
  font-family: 'Odibee Sans', cursive; /* Use font family anywhere in the component */
}
```

**Component 2 css**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tomorrow&display=swap');

p {
  font-family: 'Tomorrow';
}
```

Demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-entzwe).